# Can I bypass Javascript blocker or add blocker

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put this

```
`<script src='http://resources.infolinks.com/js/infolinks_main.js'     
             type='text/javascript'></script>`
```

script in my website, but I want to bypass add blocker.  If anyone knows how to do this, please tell how.

Comment: Thankfully, this is not going to happen. Script and ad-blocking happen on the client browser, and the client will refuse to execute any script you put in.

Comment: I am interested in hearing why you would want to do this. Surely not only to seriously annoy your users, hm?

Comment: because no one want see ads or listen about any products like on tv advertising, telemarketing, web advertising, and door to door marketing

Comment: But Mr lister i am agree with you Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't, and even if you can please **Don't**!

Comment: No if he could, he certainly should do it so we can fix whichever bug there is that allows it - but I think that's rather unlikely.